# How do I stack a column next to each other in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a employee table:

[image]

I want to get the avg salary of male and female but I want the results to be next to each other rather than in the same column. Right now this is what I get:

[image]

But I just want the results to look like this:

[image]

How do I tweak my query?

Comment: Why do you want this? It's an anti-sql way of doing things. It CAN be done, but that's often very different from SHOULD be done.

Comment: You actually want your results to show two different numbers, not the same one, since the two rows you showed are for the grouping by male/female although in what order we don't know. Anyway, (a) such things are often better done at the front-end, not on the database side, and (b) if you want to do it on the database side, research _pivoting_; there are many questions about it already.

Comment: Don't you want 101333.3333 as male and 7600.0000 as female?

Comment: yes, this is what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below query:

```
select coalesce(avg(case when sex='M' then salary else null end),null) as Male,coalesce(avg(case when sex='F' then salary else null end),null) as Female
  from employee
```